# Save current page view for sharing

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, jsf

Say I have a java/spring/jsf/jsp web application. User fills all required fields, chooses all the options, clicks generate report, spring beans do their job, database is queried for information, and user is directed to a "report" page generated according to entered information. I am looking for a way to save that page to be accessed later by link - kind of a share current page link. One example of this might be jsfiddle.net where you can enter information, save it and get a shareable link.
What i thought of, having my current knowledge, is saving some kind of url extension hash along with currently displayed page properties to database and query database for that information when someone accesses www.websiteUrl.com/extensionHash but making a query everytime someone accesses the extension seems kind of heavy on performance. 
Another way could be saving whole html page or just the content part on the server and serve later on request.
**What is the most simple/productive way of doing this?**

Comment: You seem to not have measured that "heavy" assumption? Do so and rework the question accordingly. Measuring is knowing. Usually, the answer is "cache". You placed tags on the question which doesn't tell anything about the DB and/or persistence layer used, but e.g. JPA supports 2nd level cache.

Comment: This is more of "ways to do it" than a "one way to do it" question. I know i can achieve what i want in the way i described, but is there a more productive way? Reading around "database transactions vs java code" topics gave me an impression of databases always being slower and less productive.

Comment: That's exactly why people invented caches. You seem to be heavily focused on UI layer while the problem is really in the persistence layer. If you move the focus to the correct target (the root cause of all the trouble), you'll much more likely find already given solutions/answers. Database performance has got **completely nothing** to do with "save current page for sharing". It applies to any other imaginable use case as well wherein SQL queries is involved.

Comment: Thanks, I will read on caches and their application to my case. I might have formed my question wrong, that's because i'm not familliar with this kind of stuff yet. One example of what i want to achieve might be jsfiddle.net - the way you can enter information, save it to a link and access later or share through it.

Answer (score 0):

This is one option instead of link :

What you can do is you can load the required data for that report from database when your application starts, put the data in **Application Context** ( ServletContext in Java ) and whenever you want to get the information, instead of making a database call, you get that from Application Context.( so basically its like you are loading from cache) this way your perfomance is improved.

in java, You can achieve that by implementing a listner class.

**Downvoters : please specify the reason.**

Comment: This would eliminate my concern of hitting the database everytime, a good answer. Don't understand the downvotes.